# Verify signature with public key node

Tags: node.js, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a signed data being passed to my server along with the public key in hex format, with which this data was signed. Hash algorithm is the same for all requests sha-256, but public keys are different for every request because rsa public+private pair is generated on the client.

So my question is - how can I verify the signature with public key in hex format? In node's `crypto` docs I see that I need to have a pem-format file, but I don't have one. And actually there will be many requests of this kind, so it wouldn't be good to create these files.

Comment: This really depends on the format of how the data is signed. We're going to need more information to help you. Also - if the signing keys are regenerated on the client side for every request - there's no way for the server to know what they are or even _what_ to verify. You need a way to have persistent keys, even through a session, to have any hope of verification. Otherwise, all your crypto is useless.

Comment: Hi, @Avery. Basically, on the client side I have a string `str`. Then a pair of private and public keys are generated and signature `sig = sha256(str)` is created with private key. On the next step  { `str`, `sig` and `public_key` in hex format } are sent to the server. On the server I need to verify the signature.

Comment: Why? If you're sending the pubkey with the signed data, an interceptor (whom I am guessing you are trying to protect against) can just change the key too. Can you not use a diffie-hellman algorithm here? It would let you know for sure where data comes from and it would actually work.

Comment: Do you mean the interceptor can change `str` to whatever he likes, then sign it with his own keys and send to the server? It is possible, however in my case `str` contains some additional data (like... specifically generated pseudo-random number), which he doesn't know. He can, however change other parts of `str`. So I need to hash it with sha256 to verify + sign with keys for additional security

Comment: But you're not encrypting. You're signing. **Huge** difference. Don't try to make your own crypto, it will inevitably come back to bite you. Go look up how to do a proper key exchange (diffie-hellman, for example) and properly encrypt your data. If you can, just use a pre-made SSL/TLS system to secure everything.

Comment: That is exactly what i've written in the post - "I have a signed data being passed to my server..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55329/discussion-between-avery-and-xaxa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't. Seriously. Don't.  Rolling your own cryto [will be bad](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

Instead, use https or, if you **really** must do it yourself, try to implement Diffie-Hellman. At least with DH, you aren't creating your own algorithm. As to why this is bad, consider an attacker who wants to read your data. If you merely sign it, it's really not that different than signing a letter in real life. It's your signature and (mostly) no one else can do it. But if I steal that letter of yours, write my own and sign it with *my* signature (using your name), the recipient will know it wasn't from you. But wait! What if you never contacted this recipient before? They won't know who's writing and signing using your name. Is it really you? Or is it me?  You need to do a key-exchange to prevent this.